# Adding multiple phone numbers to a single gtag code snippet for AdWords conversion tracking

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I have a client site with multiple phone numbers for different locations and would like to track all of them equally as conversions from my AdWords ads. I created a gtag from within AdWords that has a single phone number to track conversions. Is it possible to add multiple phone numbers to this code?

This is the code with x-xxx-xxx-xxxx being the phone number.

```
<script>
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    'phone_conversion_number': 'x-xxx-xxx-xxxx'
  });
</script>
```

I am hoping to modify this to track multiple phone numbers, something like this...

```
<script>
  gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
    'phone_conversion_number': 'x-xxx-xxx-xxxx',
    'phone_conversion_number': 'x-xxx-xxx-xxxx',
    'phone_conversion_number': 'x-xxx-xxx-xxxx',
    'phone_conversion_number': 'x-xxx-xxx-xxxx'
  });
</script>
```

Please let me know if this solution is reasonable or if it would make more sense to just create multiple tags on the website.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution around this?

Comment: Finally multiple phone numbers in gtag object is working or not ?